# Left navigation is always hidden on the code of conduct page

Tags: bug, code-of-conduct, left-nav

I've set my preferences to have the left navigation always visible by unchecking the following checkbox:

[image: Unchecked "Hide left navigation" in Preferences>Navigation]

This setting seems to work fine on all pages except the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) page. The Code of Conduct page shows up as if this checkbox were checked no matter what my preferences are:

[image: The left navigation is hidden on the Code of Conduct page even though my preferences say it shouldn't be]

Why is this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Either [tag:status-bydesign], or more bug: [tour] and [help] also don't show left nav, but the topic detail on Help Center (e.g. [What's Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)) shows.